# How did this bizarre edit come to be approved?

Tags: discussion

[A question was posted](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/529300/how-many-common-proper-collective-personal-nouns-in-letter) (no longer visible) , and another user took exception to the format and edited to provide what I would consider to be a defacement. It was certainly never the OP's intent, and may in fact have contributed to the deluge of DVs it received.

Should it be rolled back?

Comment: If you look at the history and who did what, it looks to me like the original author of the question approved the edit. Forget the down votes and the truly bizarre edits and the down votes, the OP is very off-topic and should be deleted anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. It's a defacement of the post. I've rolled it back (which I hope will also remove the +2 "edit approved" rep reward). I also removed the answer which reinforced the poor edit without actually being an answer.

However the question has now also been deleted (not by unilateral vote; mine was the last of the three required).

Comment: The +2 edit approved isn't removed unless you go in and reject it with your super-mod-powers.

Comment: You're right, although removing the question did remove the +2.