# Does the system track and chastize a user after a certain number of NAA flags?

Tags: discussion

Without naming and shaming… we have a “newish” and very enthusiastic user on the main who seems to suffer from impulse control and keeps posting LQ “answers”. Many of these answers are critiques of the OP's questions. In spite of the encouragement from some of us suggesting that they abide with site standards, this user  insists on cluttering up the site with LQ and NAA posts.

[Anyone that participates here on a regular basis knows exactly who I am talking about.]

Some of their answers are literally “I don’t know, but maybe someone here does”.

Moreover, they are also trying to edit other posts in a fashion which can only be described as “bizarre”. [One of these *edits* was called defacement by one Mod, and was rolled back..](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13649/how-did-this-bizarre-edit-come-to-be-approved)

I have flagged 10 of their answers as NAA (8 approved, 2 still on the LQ queue), and I am sure that many other users have flagged these as well.

Does the system kick in at some point and “warn off” this type of user? Is there a number of NAA and VLQ flags which will result in Mod notification, or even suspension?

I do not want to discourage new users, but I feel like I am cleaning up after a puppy that insists on peeing inside, even though the door is open, and the garden is sunny.

Comment: I’ve voted to delete several of that user’s questions. At least one was deleted. With enough downvoted and/or deleted answers, the user will eventually be answer-banned. So as a non-mod user, the best way for you to personally expedite the sanctions is not to flag NAA (though you can, it won’t hurt), but to downvote where the content is downvotable and delete vote where it’s not an answer. I also left a message under the mod’s answer to the defacement question you linked to, highlighting the issue with this user (though I then deleted it so the mod can see it but not create public drama).

Comment: @DanBron At every point where I felt that a DV was warranted, I have done so. Whenever I flag for NAA, I also DV. I don't know how to "delete vote'" with my lowly rep. This has become very tiresome, and would like to see some better stuff here. Is there a certain count of votes which results in a user's suspension of priveleges?

Comment: Ah, right. You need 3k or 10k or something. I forgot about that. Rep comes fast here. You’ll have it and forget about it before you know it. I’ll just say NAA flags are kinda toothless, I think all they do is put in in queue, and the only upside is more eyeballs who can then judge/DV/whatever the answer. You can also custom-mod flag the next NAA you see from this user and say “another example of the non-answers from this user I describe in <this meta post link>. Please take action.”.

Comment: Thanks for posting this question! I'm also utterly sick of reviewing this user's "answers", being polite, posting helpful comments on how to use the site, and being ignored. @DanBron The rep needed to close vote is 3k.

Comment: Noticeable, it is. I keep thinking, "Get the hint." I have tried to say when the ideas are great but the placement is off. What I will not do is to be forced into harshness to repay diarrhea of the pen.

Comment: Not moments after linking this post to yet another   LQ answer,  the newest user to fit this profile has weighed in by DVing this post...it was obvious dude. We got analytics here.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think helpful NAA/VLQ flags have weight *themselves* towards a ban. (After all, you may have helpful flags on posts that used to be bad, but were later fixed.) But flags make the post be reviewed (usually [by the review queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/247658/323179)), and what happens there to the post can cause a ban.

The ban is caused by having enough answers that were downvoted and/or deleted. But good (i.e. upvoted, non-deleted) answers help prevent an answer ban, so it can take a while for some users (especially those with >500 rep) to actually get banned. (We don't know the exact logic here, to prevent people from gaming the ban.)

In cases like these, it can be better to flag for moderator attention, giving them evidence of the problem (e.g. from your flag history if you can find it). There is a specific suspension reason for users with many low-quality posts.

See also: [the MSE guide to bans](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86998/323179)

Answer (score 2):

> Does the system kick in at some point and “warn off” this type of user?

AFAIK, while there is a warning before automatic question-ban, I don't think there is a warning before answer-ban. The user will only notice when they cannot post an answer anymore, as stated on the [help center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/answer-bans).

> Is there a number of NAA and VLQ flags which will result in Mod notification, or even suspension?

While the number of flags are recorded, there is no automatic Mod notification nor automatic suspension due to the number of flags only. Though, mods might notice the issue when observing their mod queue.

However, *review outcome* from flags may help because deleted posts (in addition to downvotes) are also counted for triggering automatic post-ban.

Otherwise, use the custom mod flag and explain clearly the issue and provide some more examples as possible to help mods notice it.